# Does anybody get these weird repeated ()()()()()() in Vim?

Tags: vim

Couple of times a day I get this, usually when typing in a browser() statement while debugging.

[image]

It repeats a whole bunch of brackets, when I only typed a pair. Usually I very quickly type "browser() *esc* :w *enter*" (without the quotes) so that I can save and go back to my R environment, and it pauses for a second, and then sticks all these brackets in. It's not really a problem, a quick Undo takes it out, just wondering why it does this. Am I moving too fast for Vim (touch typist).

I'm using Vim 7.3 on Windows 7. Does this on more than one machine. In all cases I'm also mapping caps lock to escape using sharpkeys, I don't know if that might be a factor. Anybody seeing this? Any remedy?

Thanks.

For completeness, here is my vimrc file:

```
colorscheme clarity
syntax enable
set guifont=Consolas:h10:cANSI
set number 
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
set autoindent
set smarttab
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set nocompatible
set expandtab
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
set ruler
set cursorline
set noerrorbells
set visualbell
"set guioptions-=m
set guioptions-=T
```

Comment: what plugins do you have installed? Also see if the problem still occurs if you run vim with `vim --noplugin`.

Comment: No plugins as far as I know. c:\program files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\ftplugin is empty.

Comment: Do you have anything in `vimfiles\plugin`?

Comment: Try `vim -u NONE` `:scriptnames` will tell you which plugins have been sourced.

Comment: @ThomasBrowne something like that could happen if you type some number, then insert the parentheses and then leave insert mode

Comment: @ FDinoff cyclecolor.vim. I'll take it out and see

Comment: @ Explosion Pills. Interesting. I'll try to replicate this, though it is inserting around 30-40 times so I don't see how I can be typing a double digit number with a misstype. I will also try and remove SharpKeys capslock mapping - I'll try to map it another way or go back to the old corner key dance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing on line 32 you had:

```
browser
```

Then you typed:

```
90a()<esc>
```

The mistake here being that typed "90", thinking that you were in insert/append mode, realized you weren't went into that mode, typed your parenthesis, then exited. What you actually told vim was "Append this text 90 times", and it gladly did it for you, so you ended up with:

```
browser()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()
```

It's ok, it happens to the best of us.

Comment: wow. Well spotted. I think that's probably right, but I haven't taken the time (yet) to count the 90 instances. Did you?

Comment: hmmm I only count 76 instances, but it's possible I chopped some off at the end of my screen capture. I will report back on the number of copies next time this "problem" occurs.

Comment: No, I just assumed that it was cut off since you can't see the right-hand side scrollbar or window close button in the frame.